# How to fetch data in page.tsx(server component) and it contains a client component with two buttons that refetches data in Nextjs 13.4.19

Tags: javascript, fetch, next.js13

I have an api url `http://localhost:4001/api/pics?access=${querystr}` in which querystr is either public, private or all. In nextjs app (v13.4.19). In the page.tsx which is a server component I fetch the data the first time

```
import React from 'react';
import TableComp from './TableComp';

async function getData(querystr: string) {
  const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:4001/api/pics?access=${querystr}`)
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch data')
  }
  return res.json()
}


const Page = async({}: PageProps) => {
  const data = await getData('all');
  return (
    <>
      <TableComp inpdata={data} getData={getData}/>
    </>
  )
}

export default Page;
```

TableComp is a client component that contains 3 tab buttons and a div to display fetched data. The issue is I am unable to figure out if on click of the tab button the fetch data can be called again and the data gets refreshed.

```
"use client"
const TableComp = ({inpdata, getData}: TableCompProp) => {
  const [tab, setTab] = useState('all');
  useEffect(()=>{
    if(tab === 'all') {
        getData('all')
    }
    
    if(tab === 'public') {
        getData('public')
    }
    
    if(tab === 'private') {
        getData('private')
    }
  
  }, [tab])
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={()=>setTab('all')}>All</button>
      <button onClick={()=>setTab('public')}>Public</button>
      <button onClick={()=>setTab('private')}>Private</button>
      
      <div>
        {inpdata}
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default TableComp;
```

I need help in figuring out if its possible or if any other strategy can be used to do the same. Any suggestions will be very helpful as I am in the process of learning Nextjs 13